# WMI SQL Query error

Tags: c#, wmi

I keep getting an error output for the WMI Query that has to do with the OR statement. I read that the or has to be placed after the AND. What am I doing wrong?

```
WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'iexplore.exe' OR TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe' ");
```

Error is this: "Invalid query"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I had to put the or statement first!

```
WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE (TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe' OR TargetInstance.Name = 'iexplore.exe') AND TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'");
```